# Passing variable arguments : python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a code that takes file and class names, and operates over it. An example will explain it much more clearly than I possibly can:

I have a file `test.py` that goes as:

```
import pandas as pd
from preProcess import preProcess
from visualise import visualise

df=pd.read_csv('input.csv')

li1=["preProcess","visualise"]
li2=["minMax","pca"]

for i in range(len(li1)):
    x = getattr(getattr(__import__(li1[i]),li1[i]), li2[i])
    a=x(df)
    # does some more stuff...
```

`li1` contains name of the modules and `li2` contains the name of the classes in the corresponding modules.

To make it a bit clearer, `preProcess.py` goes as:

```
class minMax():
    def __init__(df):
    # does something
```

and `visualise.py` goes as:

```
class pca():
    def __init__(df):
    # does something
```

The line `x = getattr(getattr(__import__(li1[i]),li1[i]), li2[i])` gives me the classes `minMax` and `pca`.

Now the thing is that this code works perfectly fine if `__init__` takes only one argument. But, what if it requires more than 1 arguments? For eg., `pca` could have been:

```
class pca():
    def __init__(df,metaData):
    # does something
```

What should I do in such a case? Any help would be appreciated.

If the question is not clear, please drop a comment. I would provide a more detailed explanation then. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you should utilize the spread operator. maybe this snippet helps:

```py
class X:
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

args = [2, 'hellow']
x = X(*args)
```

**EDIT**: this is just an outline of the general approach. for a more comprehensive overview of how this approach is applicable to this specific problem, please check the discussion on this answer.

Comment: i wonder who is marking down without commenting. It really doesnt help anyone.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but there will be a problem with `args` in my implementation. There can be about 100 such function, that too overloaded. It won't be feasible for me... (PS: I didn't downvote)

Comment: @MEdwin yeah its seems weird, but anyways internet is going to internet.

Comment: @AnkitKumar ok I couldn't understand your issue properly, could you elaborate a little bit more why is it going to be a problem? I suspect you are going to have a list of modules and classes, and a list of initialization arguments for each of those classes, and you need to create one instance of any of said classes with the corresponding list of initialization parameter and do something with it, right?

Comment: @EugeneGhanizadehKhoub I want the code to be scalable. I have certain classes with that have overloaded methods, i.e, `f(a,b=None)`. To make a list for `args`, I'll need to check if the user passes `b` or not. What you are saying is 100% correct, but I cannot use `if-else` statements in my code due to scalability issue.

Comment: @AnkitKumar in that case could you elaborate more how do you receive the initialization parameters? my blind suggestion would be at this point to not create dynamic argument lists, but actually cache the metadata of how many arguments should be passed to each class beforehand (maybe hard-code them or use [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)), and then construct argument lists strictly based on that cached metadata without having any `if-else`s.

Comment: @EugeneGhanizadehKhoub I modified my code to take a dataframe and a dictionary as input (for all the functions). In that dictionary, I can beforehand add all of the variables, and use them in a function, if needed. Accepting your answer because it was really helpful to come up with this idea. But please edit your answer to include this idea. To clarify, I changed `test.py` to have the line `a=x(df,dict)` and all functions `f` to `f(df,*args)`. Then, I'm using `args` in the functions I need (and it works as I want it to). Thanks...